# How to pass POSTed multipart/form-data from php to python

Tags: php, python, multipartform-data

I have a form that's used to upload file to a python script, using code like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="script.py" method="post">
<input type="file" name="foo">
```

script.py has logic to process the uploaded file.

Now, I have a different application that's written in php that paints the page, and that application needs to accept the upload instead.

Because file processing logic lives in script.py, which I do not control, I would like to simply call script.**py** from script.**php**, and the environment (request variables, stdin with file data, etc.) to magically be passed on, without having to touch script.py.

Conceptually, I want to do this, except it doesnt work (form data never makes it to script.py):

```
$this_script=$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'];
$fullcmd=dirname($this_script).'/'.'script.py';
exec($fullcmd);
```

I have tried proc_open() without much luck.

Thank you.

Comment: This will be a mess. Better stick to 1 programming language. Why can't you simply write everything in Python?

Comment: ***NO.*** Just use one server language. Normally I advocate for python, but pick PHP or python, not both. One.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Real life is not as simple and sometimes your need to integrate applications written by different teams, which you don't control and when "just rewrite in language X" is not an answer that will fly. Anyway, i believe I know answer to my own question, so this thread can be closed. Thanks.